# on slick 2.0, I find I can not store user defined field

Tags: scala, slick

I use slick 2.0 rc
I have defined field UserId:

```
case class UserId(id: Long) extends AnyVal with BaseId
object UserId extends IdCompanion[UserId]
```

when I use it:

```
class Resources(tag: Tag) extends Table[Resource](tag, "RESOURCE") {
def id = column[Long]("ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
def owner = column[UserId]("Owner")
def types = column[String]("Type")
def withuser = foreignKey("User_FK", owner, Users)(_.id)
```

it give me compile error as:

```
[error] C:\assigment\slick-advanced\app\models\Resource.scala:15: could not find
implicit value for parameter tm: scala.slick.ast.TypedType[models.UserId]
[error]   def owner = column[UserId]("Owner")
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20828136/on-slick-2-0-i-find-i-can-not-implicit-user-defined-column/20830170

Comment: @cvogt I think this issue is because I defined UserId as object while the another question is not duplicate for I defined that UseId as class

Comment: Sorry, you believe wrong. Where does IdCompanion come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need an object UserId. You need an implicit that describes the mapping. See http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.0-RC1/userdefined.html