# on slick 2.0, I find I can not implicit user defined column

Tags: scala, slick

I use slick 2.0 rc
I have defined field `UserId`:

```
trait TypedId extends Any {
   def value: Long
}

trait HasId[ID <: TypedId] {
  _: Table[_] =>
  def id: Column[ID]
}

case class UserId(value:Long) extends AnyVal with TypedId

case class User(id: Option[UserId],
                email: String,
                firstName: String,
                lastName: String,
                phone:String)
```

when I use it:

```
class Users(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "users") with HasId[Option[UserId]] {
    def * = (id.?, email, firstName , lastName , phone )<> (User.tupled, User.unapply)
    def id= column[Option[UserId]]("ID", O.AutoInc, O.PrimaryKey)
    def email = column[String]("EMAIL", O.NotNull)

    def firstName = column[String]("FIRST_NAME", O.NotNull)

    def lastName = column[String]("LAST_NAME", O.NotNull)
    def phone =column[String]("PHONE", O.NotNull)
}
```

it give me compile error as:

```
[error] C:\assigment\slick-advanced\app\models\User.scala:27: could not find imp
licit value for parameter tm: scala.slick.ast.TypedType[Option[models.UserId]]
[error]   def id= column[Option[UserId]]("ID", O.AutoInc, O.PrimaryKey)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [on slick 2.0, I find I can not store user defined field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20827533/on-slick-2-0-i-find-i-can-not-store-user-defined-field)

Comment: @Akos Krivachy that is different that question error is because I use object. but this question I use the class but still have error

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a duplicate of the already answered question, which can be found here: [on slick 2.0, I find I can not store user defined field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20827533/on-slick-2-0-i-find-i-can-not-store-user-defined-field/20827862)

Comment: do you find your duplication are actually the same link and same page?

Comment: you mean the UserId only can only be defined by MappedTo I can not use the trait TypedId to defined it? this one is different from the duplicate you said, that one I use the object as UserId, this time I use the class as UserId.

Comment: You cannot use an object as UserId. And yes, either extend `MappedTo` (but be aware of an open bug with MappedTo) or write a `MappedColumnType`.